# Why fSpy addon can't be enabled

Tags: add-on, fspy

I am trying to install the fSpy add-on for Blender. I've downloaded it as a .zip file and went to user preferences to install it. However, it does not show up in any list of add-ons in user prefs.
[image]

When I checked the console it repeatedly shows the following:

```
Modules Installed () from '/Users/lihechen/Downloads/All Files/Plugins/Blender/fSpy-Blender-master.zip' into '/Users/lihechen/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.81/scripts/addons'
```

But nothing shows up.
Can anyone please help? I'm using Blender 2.81

Comment: After install you want to see a folder `fspy_blender` in your addons folder `/Users/lihechen/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.81/scripts/addons`  Can simply drag it there from archive manager.  Sometimes github zips don't install as expected.. could have produced a  folder named `fspy-blender-master` in there instead which will not work..

Comment: You've probably downloaded the *repository* as a zip file (green clone or download button). Try the latest release from the *releases* page: https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases as stated in the [readme](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender#1-download-the-add-on).

Answer (score 2):

New answer (after getting feedback in the comments):
The file you are trying to install is the wrong one (i.e. the repository downloaded as a zip file). Try with the release file instead.

Old answer:
I suspect that it is in fact installed but not showing up in the list because it is not enabled yet (your screenshot is only showing enabled add-ons).

First, uncheck the checkbox that says "Enabled Add-ons Only" to be able to find the add-on, then check the checkbox for the add-on to enable it.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Unfortunately, I've looked through all available add-ons (including those not enabled) and I haven't found the add-on.

Comment: I don't recognize the naming of the .zip-file you are trying to install, maybe you should try with a file from this page instead https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases ? I suspect you have downloaded the whole git-repo, which probably wont work. Let me know if this solves your problem and I'll update my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I’ve updated my answer so you can accept it as the correct one.